# django-celery redis memoryerror

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I'm using django+celery with redis as the broker, and one of my task involves reading large file about 25MB in size and returning the results, by which another task is chained to process the results.

I'm encountering the error here which due to my lack of familiarity with redis, I'm appealing for help. What might be the problem?

```
[2013-06-23 22:45:41,241: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: MemoryError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 363, in start
    component.start()
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 395, in start
    self.consume_messages()
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 480, in consume_messages
    readers[fileno](fileno, event)
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 770, in handle_event
    self._callbacks[queue](message)
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 479, in _callback
    self.qos.append(message, message.delivery_tag)
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 117, in append
    dumps([message._raw, EX, RK])) \
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1808, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/home/property/virtualenv/property_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1705, in _execute_transaction
    [args for args, options in cmds]))
MemoryError
```

Not sure if it provides any hint, but checking the maxmemory setting on redis server doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "3758096384"
```

Comment: does it happens every time / randomly or after bit of time that the worker is running ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the memory error is not on the redis side but at client side (celery worker)

My guess is that the worker is running out of memory

You should make sure the celery process can actually allocate the result coming from redis into memory.

If this happens after few tasks are executed it means that you dont have enough memory to handle the concurrency you set or that you are leaking memory (leaving references of the object from redis) somewhere

Comment: good suggestion. is there a memory limit for the clery process to operate under? What might be the best way to investigate this memory issue.

Comment: @goh that depends on your setup but normally you dont have a memory limit; is suggest you to check your memory usage over time on your worker machine while running celery (and while processing the 25MB tasks)